# JQuery Navbar Background-image shuffling issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted my Navbar's background-image to shuffle through different images set on a timer. I got it to shuffle but the menu and my logo disappear when the image fades away and comes back when the next image shows up. Another issue I have is that the image doesnt fade into a new image but it goes blank then shows the next image.

Issues:
1) Menu and Logo fade along with background-image.
2) Background-image goes blank when changing to next image.

Tried:
1) I tried using .not on my var element but no joy. I created a class called .ignore for my Logo and Menu. 
2) Not sure how to solve this as I am new to JQuery.

JQuery Code:

```
    $(function(){  
    var i =0;
    var images = ['assets/img/storm-ocean-hurricane-florida-beach-coast-travel.jpg','assets/img/arctic_sunset.jpg','assets/img/fallflood.jpg','assets/img/landscape-with-fog-and-chimney-smoke-at-sunset.jpg'];
    var image = $('.navbar').not('.ignore');
    image.css('background-image', 'url(assets/img/storm-ocean-hurricane-florida-beach-coast-travel.jpg)');
    setInterval(function(){  
        image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] +')');
            image.fadeIn(1000);
        });
        if(i == (images.length - 1)){
            i = 0; 
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }, 5000);
})
```

[image: The Menu follows the user down through the site and the logo stays where it is.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything explicitly wrong with your JS, but I think you can solve all of your issues by creating a new HTML element inside your `navbar` that is meant to only hold the background image, and is positioned behind all other elements to not interfere with them. Markup would just be `<div class="navbar__bg"></div>`.

CSS for such an element would be like:

```
.navbar {
    position: relative; /* needed to allow your bg element to properly position */
}

.navbar__bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

And you'd change the fourth line of your jQuery to:

`var image = $('.navbar__bg');`

> "Another issue I have is that the image doesnt fade into a new image but it goes blank then shows the next image."

As for this, your code is written to currently fade out completely, change the image, then fade in. Are you saying you want to crossfade two images to blend into one another? This would require overlapping multiple elements as they simultaneously fade in and out. A crossfade cannot be done by changing `background-image` on one element.

Comment: Ive tried doing the div idea before but it would never fill up the entire screen like I wanted it to. So for the crossfade I just need to add in another background-image to my section?

Comment: Using those left/top/right/bottom properties with absolute positioning will allow you to size the div to fit anything, including your entire screen. If you can't get it working, paste a JSFiddle here and we'll work through it quickly. For a crossfade, you would need two overlapping absolute positioned elements, both with background-image, and then you'd toggle opacity between them (which you could still use fadeIn/fadeOut for). There are also many jQuery slideshow plugins you could use to accomplish this with less work.

Comment: Didnt work. Shrank it down to a small bar. I tried it with mixing some of my stuff in and I have a solid white bar on the bottom of it and the video

Comment: Again, please create a JSFiddle so we can work through the problem. Can't help without seeing all the HTML and CSS.

Comment: The code I wrote in the example above worked fine for me! Added it into your JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1dzqt0uj/1/ Added a background color just to show things are working since the images aren't hosted here.

Comment: Ill do some research into the Crossfade as thats going into a whole other topic. Thx for the help!